# Find the velocity of a flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is: 
Find the velocity of the flow described by the velocity potential given in the polar coordinates $φ$$(r, θ)$ = $θ$,
where $x = r cos θ$ and $y = r sin θ$,
$r > 0, 0 ≤ θ < 2π$
and sketch the flow.

I have no idea where to start!
We have not been given a definition of the velocity potential.
I feel like there is something missing from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia reference:

- [Potential flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow)

Flow velocities $(u,v)$ are obtained from the flow potential $\phi$ as follows:
$$
u = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \quad ; \quad
v = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}
$$
First transform to Cartesian coordinates and then take the derivatives:
$$
\phi = \theta = \arctan(y/x) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
u = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2} \; ,  \; v = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (u,v)= \frac{(-y,x)}{r^2}
$$

Wikipedia reference:

- [Two-dimensional flows: Irrotational vortex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_flows#Irrotational_vortex)

You have an irrotational vortex with strength $2\pi$ and rotating counterclockwise:

[image]